# Main Difference between PHP and Servlet

Tags: php, servlets

I'm reading some documents about both Servlets and PHP. These document have the same thing about the advantage of these tools such as: that  they replace a weak point of html (just a static page, cannot be used for dynamic data).

And I have some thinking of my own about a difference: Servlet+JSP will make it easier for a pure Java Developer to touch Web Platform (Or, connecting between Java developer and web developer). Nevertheless, PHP is lighter, it means PHP doesn't need heavy knowledge. (in this case, the Java language).

But, I really don't see what the main difference between these technologies. (That you must choose this language instead of other) .

thanks :)

Comment: `But, I really don't see what main difference between these technology. (that you must choose this language instead of other)` -> I am afraid you won't get an answer to this question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What is actually the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlet to PHP is similar to say Java to C#, Both have good and bad. But I think the major reason to choose between the two is, who are your programmers and what do they know. Since you already know the goods and bad of each platform.